# Getting Calendar from Lotus Traveler

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

I need to get the calendar data from Lotus Traveler.

But it is hard to find any material on how to get anything.  There are some examples regarding adding to Lotus Notes, but no info on the other way.

Is it like contacting an exchange server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lotus Traveler is a middle ware tool which sits between a domino server and mobile devices which have apps specifically defined to interface with it. For security and confidentiality there is minimal API documentation for the Traveler interfaces.

You can access calenders directly from the domino server through standard domino views. There are several views available in the standard Notes Mail/Calendar templates and if what you need is not available, you can extend the design of the database with your own views.

Hope this helps - Newbs

Answer (score 0):

With Lotus Notes Traveler installed on the server, you can get to your mail, contacts and calendar on e.g. an iPhone using the ActiveSync protocol. So you can say that Traveler emulates Exchange.

If you are looking to retrieve calendar data from another Notes/Domino database then you can extend the mail database as per Henrys answer.

If you want to access calendar data from outside of Notes/Domino (e.g. from a different non-Domino application server) then you can create your own REST API that you can access with REST web services. You can also have [Domino Data Service](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=Domino%20Data%20Service) create the REST interface for you.